# Passing Incomplete Parameter List in Python

Tags: python, parameters, functional-programming, reduce

I'm trying to use a reduce in Python, but I've found the function I need to call takes 2 parameters.

Is there a way for me to pass one of the parameters in, but not pass the first one?

Like so

```
b = 10    
reduce(foo, range(20), 0)

def foo(a, b):
     return a + b
```

Comment: I'm not sure `reduce` is what you're looking for. `reduce` is made to pair items in a list, continuously "combining" them into one until there is only one item left. Are you sure you just don't want to iterate over the entire list with a `map`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? May be a sample input/output might help us to know your intention and can give better answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [lambda](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) to wrap `foo`:

```
reduce(lambda a,c: foo(a,b), range(20), 0)
```

where `c` will be not used.

Comment: Are you sure this is what the OP is asking for? Could you say a little bit more about why one would want to do this? This seems like an unnecessarily complex way of calculating b * 20.

Comment: @senderle I assume that b*20 is just an example. OP asks how to pass one parameter, and disregard second. This is one possible way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, indeed -- I just can't think of any scenario in which `reduce(f, range(n), 0)` is the best way to accumulate the same action `n` times, and I was wondering if you had something in mind. (Otherwise I might steer the OP away from this approach!)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't need to explicitly pass zero:

```
print reduce(foo, range(20))
```

output:

```
190
```

Another interpretation of your question is, for the method `foo(a, b)` you want `a` to always be 10.
If that is the case, you're not looking for `reduce` - you're looking for `map`. And you can achieve the "setting one of the parameters as 'fixed'" behavior by wrapping your `foo` method

```
def wrapper(f, a):
    def x(b):
        return f(a, b)
    return x

def foo(a, b):
    return a+b

print map(wrapper(foo, 10), range(11))
```

output:

```
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```